# Griffon boolean assignment bug?

Tags: groovy, griffon

i have the following code

in the model

```
@Bindable boolean readOnly
```

in the view

```
checkBox(text: 'Read Only', constraints:'wrap',selected:bind(target: model, targetProperty:'readOnly'))
```

in the controller

```
new groovy.swing.SwingBuilder().frame(title:'File opened',pack:true,show:true){
  panel(layout: new MigLayout('fill'), border: titledBorder('Content')){
    separator(constraints:"cell 0 1")
    textArea(text: part1 , editable: false)
    separator(constraints:"cell 0 2")
    textArea(text: part2 , editable: false)
    separator(constraints:"cell 0 1")
    t1 = textArea(text: part3 , editable: "${model.readOnly}",columns:50)
    separator(constraints:"cell 0 2")
    t2 = textArea(text: part4 , editable: "${model.readOnly}")
    separator(constraints:"cell 0 3")
    button('Save!', actionPerformed: save, constraints: 'span 5, bottom, right')
  }
}
```

but its always enabled , doesnt matter if checkbox is selected or not.

```
system.out.println("${model.readOnly}")
```

shows `true` and `false` correctly but for some reason on the frame its always set to `true`

note: also assignment `boolean a = "${model.readOnly}"` sets a always to true , or `if "${model.readOnly}" == true` or `if ("${model.readOnly}")` work as its always `true`

oh and also setting size in the frame such as

```
new groovy.swing.SwingBuilder().frame(title:'File opened',pack:true,show:true, size : [640,480]){
```

doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The text areas need to be bound, not just set.  As written it will read the value only once.

```
t1 = textArea(text: part3 , editable: bind (source: model, sourceProperty:'readOnly') ,columns:50)
```

(b) the one more thing, combining pack aid size generally doesn't work.  Remove the `pack:true` from the declaration whenever you declare a size.